# Long text without space wrapping inside the column

Tags: css

I have three columns in a row and a third column with long text without any space. Because of the long text I am not able to wrap the text inside the column and getting a horizontal scroll bar on the page. Is there any way to add space after the special character tilde ~ through css? I cannot add space through code as it is generating via database.

Text formatting is below:
Afghanistan~Albania~Algeria~Andorra~Angola~Antigua~Barbuda~Argentina~Armenia~Australia~Austria~Azerbaijan~Bahamas~Bahrain~Bangladesh~Barbados~Belarus~Belgium~

**Here is the example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/nupqS/1/

```
table{width:100%;}
td{
    vertical-align:top;
    font:normal 9pt arial;
    padding:10px;
    width:33%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nupqS/2/

**use max-width css only**

```
td {
vertical-align: top;
font: normal 9pt arial;
padding: 10px;
width: 33%;
max-width: 200px;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

and if you want to remove the **~** you can use jquery like this

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nupqS/5/

**use max-width css , jquery and blank space**

```
var textarea = $("td.td3");
textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(new RegExp("~","g")," "));
```

**use max-width css , jquery and breack **

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nupqS/6/

Comment: Thanks dude, but instead of pixel can't we add percentage? This table should be fuild.

Comment: I tried to add max-width:33%; but unfortunate it is not working. Can you please check?

Comment: since your goal is to remove the ~ why don't you just use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use CSS to add a character after each occurrence of a specific character. You can do this with JavaScript, however. Assuming for simplicity that the relevant cells can be recognized by the class `t3` and only that class is assigned to them, you can add U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE after each occurrence of a tilde as follows:

```
<script>
var t = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i < t.length; i++)
  if(t[i].className === 'td3')
    t[i].innerHTML = t[i].innerHTML.replace(/~/g, '~\u200b'); 
</script>
```

You should remove `word-wrap: break-word`, since it is literally for breaking words, and you don’t want to have words br oken arbitr arily in a b rutal wa y.